# Android Samsung Galaxy A13 5G Model SM-A136U1 device issue as "Your device isn't compatible with this version"

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, android-device-manager

I have tried the below steps to clear the cache data in play store, but still we are not able to get the INSTALL option for our app in Play Store.

- CLEAR CACHE > OK.
- CLEAR DATA > OK. under Apps or Application Manager Settings

Here we are getting error message in Play Store.

> Your device isn't compatible with this version

I have provided the native platforms support "arm64-v8a" architecture for our app, which will runs on build gradle in Android Studio as below format in our app Production Build Released.

**ndk.abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'**

We are using `Samsung Galaxy A13 5G Model SM-A136U1 One UI Core 4.1 Android Version 12`, but for this device it is unable to download our app from Google Play Store.

I have tried the several forums with various combinations of order without success. I have researched this issue on the internet and have tried just about all these recommendations. Factory resetting to not convolute cause and effect with settings as I try something new. But still no use after these changes done.

Could anyone please provide exact reason why our app is not compatible with this device version?

Could you please provide any troubleshoot for this issue from Production PlayStore build, which is not yet compatible with the latest Samsung Android device versions.

Could you please provide any architecture changes/hardware required to provide support for our Production PlayStore build to our customer device name Samsung Galaxy A13 5G Model SM-A136U1 device?

Could you please provide any additional permissions (or) new enhancements needed to download on customer device name - Samsung Galaxy A13 5G Model SM-A136U1 device.

Answer (score 1):

it's correct, but not all developers happened so, i got that when user change device Galaxy S23 to S24, both Android 14. diffence is S23 now software update can max oneui 6.0 and S24 is max oneui6.1. And, i refered this article ([This app isn't compatible with the latest version of android. in android 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77818852/this-app-isnt-compatible-with-the-latest-version-of-android-in-android-14)).

know my build.gradle changed like this, and works fine to me.
(armeabi > armeabi, arm64-v8a)

android {
nbiFilters {
'armeabi', 'arm64-v8a'

my app use a lot of security solutions. maybe this was the cause.

CryptHelper.c - C++ language file

> app/main/libs/jni/CryptHelper.so was missing when build this app
> into Galaxy S24 device and error follows "Your device isn't compatible...."

CyptHelper.so contain AESCryption so its usage was fast use security functions

hope helpful solving problem like this. thx

Answer (score 0):

You probably already figured it out but I was told that the reason you are seeing this is that the device's ABI is armeabi-v7a and you have probably only compiled the arm64-v8a version and uploaded it to the Play Store. I am just passing on some info I was told. They mentioned that you can compile multiple APKs and the Play Store will pick the correct one for each device but I don't develop mobile apps so that is all foreign to me.

I hope this helps you in some way.